# Why does 2D assignment not work as expected in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```py
    for (old_point, new_point) in zip(masked_indices, masked_new_indices):
        row, col = old_point
        new_row, new_col = new_point
        
        new_img[row, col] = img[new_row, new_col]
```

Where `new_img` and `img` are both 1024x1024x3 ndarrays, and `masked_indices` and `masked_new_indices` are both 80000x2 ndarrays.

Why does this statement not have the same behaviour?

```py
    new_img[masked_indices] = img[masked_new_indices]
```

And is there a way to optimize this `for` loop into a more NumPy-ish style?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since `new_img` is three dimensional, I have to specify two indexes. Trying to use a 2D value in a single index was what was causing the unexpected behaviour.

This had the effect that I was going for, although it's not very pretty:

```py
new_img[masked_indices[:, 0], masked_indices[:, 1], :] = img[masked_new_indices[:, 0], masked_new_indices[:, 1], :]
```